# Transform on MySql subquery

Tags: mysql

I want to mysql join 2 tables in a special way.

Here are my 2 tables:

Rights

> <kbd>`right_id`</kbd>
>   <kbd>`thumbnail`</kbd>
>   <kbd>`enabled`</kbd>
>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>        <kbd>`img1.png`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      
>   <kbd>`2`</kbd>        <kbd>`img2.png`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      
>   <kbd>`3`</kbd>        <kbd>`img3.png`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>

Right Strings

> <kbd>`right_id`</kbd>
>   <kbd>`language`</kbd>
>   <kbd>`string_key`</kbd>  
>   <kbd>`string value`</kbd>
>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>       
>   <kbd>`en`</kbd>      
>   <kbd>`short_header`</kbd>
>   <kbd>`Right 1`</kbd>     
>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>       
>   <kbd>`de`</kbd>      
>   <kbd>`short_header`</kbd>
>   <kbd>`Recht 1`</kbd>     
>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>       
>   <kbd>`de`</kbd>      
>   <kbd>`long_header`</kbd> 
>   <kbd>`Langer Text`</kbd> 
>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>       
>   <kbd>`en`</kbd>      
>   <kbd>`long_header`</kbd> 
>   <kbd>`Long Text`</kbd>   
>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>       
>   <kbd>`en`</kbd>      
>   <kbd>`content`</kbd>     
>   <kbd>`Bla Bla Bla`</kbd> 
>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>       
>   <kbd>`de`</kbd>      
>   <kbd>`content`</kbd>     
>   <kbd>`Bla Bla Bla`</kbd>

This repeats for other languages and all rights as well.

Is it possible to create a query that will return all rights as only one row in the following format?

> <kbd>`right_id`</kbd><kbd>`thumbnail`</kbd><kbd>`enabled`</kbd><kbd>`short_header_en`</kbd><kbd>`short_header_de`</kbd><kbd>`long_header_en`</kbd><kbd>`long_header_de`</kbd><kbd>`content_en`</kbd>     <kbd>`content_de`</kbd>     
>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>       <kbd>`img1.png`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd>      <kbd>`Right 1`</kbd>        <kbd>`Recht 1`</kbd>        <kbd>`Long Text`</kbd>     <kbd>`Langer Text`</kbd>   <kbd>`Bla Bla Bla`</kbd>    <kbd>`Bla Bla Bla`</kbd>

I assume that mysql has some kind of transform for subqueries but I do not know what to even look for.

Thank you

Comment: @jothi That would return 6+ rows for each right. I only want one row though.

Comment: you are looking for Group_concat?

Comment: your question is nice formated. but not very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a table pivot issue, not sure if it's what you exactly want or not, but try it.

```
SELECT
    r.right_id, r.thumbnail, r.enabled,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CONCAT(rs.string_key, '_', rs.`language`) = 'short_header_en' THEN string_value END) AS `short_header_en`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CONCAT(rs.string_key, '_', rs.`language`) = 'short_header_de' THEN string_value END) AS `short_header_de`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CONCAT(rs.string_key, '_', rs.`language`) = 'long_header_en' THEN string_value END) AS `long_header_en`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CONCAT(rs.string_key, '_', rs.`language`) = 'long_header_de' THEN string_value END) AS `long_header_de`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CONCAT(rs.string_key, '_', rs.`language`) = 'content_en' THEN string_value END) AS `content_en`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CONCAT(rs.string_key, '_', rs.`language`) = 'content_de' THEN string_value END) AS `content_de`
FROM rights r
INNER JOIN right_strings rs
ON r.right_id = rs.right_id
GROUP BY r.right_id
```

For dynamic table pivot:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN CONCAT(rs.string_key, '_', rs.`language`) = ''',
      string_key, '_', `language`
      ''' THEN rs.string_value END) AS ',
      string_key, '_', `language`
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM right_strings;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT r.right_id, r.thumbnail, r.enabled, ',
    @sql,
    ' FROM rights r
    INNER JOIN right_strings rs
    ON r.right_id = rs.right_id
    GROUP BY r.right_id;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thank you. This is already getting there. Since there are possibly more languages in the future, is it possible to auto create the column names? I do not want to be worried about forgetting to update this query for each new language.

Comment: @MichaelFrey Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following pivot query:

```
SELECT t1.right_id, t1.thumbnail, t1.enabled,
    MAX(CASE WHEN language = 'en' AND string_key = 'short_header' THEN string_value ELSE NULL) AS short_header_en,
    MAX(CASE WHEN language = 'de' AND string_key = 'short_header' THEN string_value ELSE NULL) AS short_header_de,
    MAX(CASE WHEN language = 'en' AND string_key = 'long_header'  THEN string_value ELSE NULL) AS long_header_en,
    MAX(CASE WHEN language = 'de' AND string_key = 'long_header'  THEN string_value ELSE NULL) AS long_header_de,
    MAX(CASE WHEN language = 'en' AND string_key = 'content'      THEN string_value ELSE NULL) AS content_en,
    MAX(CASE WHEN language = 'de' AND string_key = 'content'      THEN string_value ELSE NULL) AS content_de
FROM Rights t1 INNER JOIN RightsStrings t2
    ON t1.right_id = t2.right_id
GROUP BY t1.right_id
```

Comment: Missed `END` for `CASE WHEN` clause.

Comment: Thank you. This is already getting there. Since there are possibly more languages in the future, is it possible to auto create the column names? I do not want to be worried about forgetting to update this query for each new language.

Comment: @MichaelFrey You would need to use dynamic SQL to handle this.